# Converting an array of strings to an Object of coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of strings that looks like this:

```
let array = ["35.9, "33.2", "31.4"]
```

I want to convert the array to an object that has the following structure:

```
let data = [
    { x :  0, y : 35.9 },
    { x :  1, y : 33.2 },
    { x :  2, y : 31.4 }
];
```

Where x is the index of the value, which is y (no longer a String). I've been looking through the Array and Object API and am pretty clueless. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `array.map((y, x) => ({ x, y }))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array = ["35.9", "33.2", "31.4"];

const result = array.map(function(value, index) {
  return {x: index, y: value}
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map((item, index) => ({ x: index, y: item }));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract up votes.

Comment: @DaveHogan Thank you for reminding me. I'll pay attention to it later！

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using .map method of an array . Also since you have string array initially , you can use Number("str") to convert to number .

```js
let array = ["35.9", "33.2", "31.4"];



var res = array.map((obj,index) => {
    return {x:index,y:Number(obj)}
 })
 
console.log(res)
```